# loading directive problem with displaying content

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, directive

I've created a a directive called **v-loading**

its duty is to show some spinner or some text like `loading ...` when calling API

for example if you put this directive on div element like this and pass it `true` value
it will show a loading text

```js
<div v-loading="loading">
   some content from Api
</div>

<script setup lang="ts">
   import {ref} from 'vue'
   const loading=ref(true)
</script>
```

the problem is that m the content will not be **displayed** after **loading** get false .

You can see working example [here](https://playcode.io/1623460)

**directives/loading.ts**

```js
import Loading from '../components/loading.vue'
import { createApp, ref, inject } from 'vue'

const vLoadingSymbol = Symbol()

export function useIsLoading () {
  const isLoading = inject(vLoadingSymbol)
  if (!isLoading) {
    console.error('Has no isLoading provide!')
  }
  return isLoading
}

export default {
  beforeMount (el:any, binding:any) {
    // create VLoading component
    const vLoading = createApp(Loading)
    // use ref binding state
    const isLoading = ref(false)
    isLoading.value = binding.value
    // provide isLoading state for VLoading component
    vLoading.provide(vLoadingSymbol, isLoading)

    if (!['relative', 'absolute'].includes(el.style.position)) {
      el.style.position = 'relative'
    }

    // bind isLoading ref on el
    el.vLoading = isLoading

    vLoading.mount(el)
  },
  updated (el:any, binding:any) {
    el.vLoading.value = binding.value
  }
}
```

what's the problem , and How can I fix this ?